# What are the differences between Spring Frameworks of Java?

Tags: java, spring

currently I'm working in a project using Spring, this is the first time i learn Spring framework, I haved learnt some experience in spring 2.0. Then I have a question want to know "What is the difference between Spring 2.0, Spring 2.5 and Spring 3.0".
Thank for take your time!

Comment: This kind of question is far too broad and open ended for an in depth answer.  You need to do your own reading / research.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, when using a framework for the first time, its generally best practice to use the newest stable release, as that has the most features and fixes.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean what is different other than 0.5 then.
Firstly on Spring Source's website has the details you need.

[Whats new in 2.0 and 2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/new-in-2.html)

[Whats new in 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html)

For my money, the differences that matter are:

3.0 required Java 5. 2.5 could work off Java 1.4

2.5+ limited Annotations are supported. 3.0 you can do everything in annotations.

Also new in 3.0:

- Spring Expresssion Language
- Spring Converters
- Adding Java Config module to Core Spring
- Spring RESTful Web Services are new
- More namespaces etc.